# How to parse HTML and preformat using php

Tags: php, html

I have text like this `Too early to post? http://www.somewebsite.com/article/226973` I want to parse the hyperlinks in the text and make the text look like so `Too early to post? <a href="http://www.entrepreneur.com/article/226973" target="_blank">http://www.entrepreneur.com/article/226973</a>` I want to do this but I have no idea where to start from or what regexp to use.

Comment: if the content is always in the same format like you've posted, it might be easier to use explode() rather than Preg_match()

Comment: What do you mean by explode. This is a string.

Comment: You should show us what you already tried.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$s = 'Too early to post? https://www.somewebsite.com/article/226973'; 
$parsed = preg_replace('@(https?://([-\w\.]+[-\w])+(:\d+)?(/([\w/_\.#-]*(\?\S+)?[^\.\s])?)?)@', '<a href="$1" target="_blank">$1</a>', $s); 
echo $parsed;
```